# Can I preserve local ivy repository in Bluemix BUILD & DEPLOY?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

Bluemix BUILD & DEPLOY seems to provide a new virtual machine for every build. Ivy local repository (~/.ivy2) is cleared and dependency jar download runs during every build. That takes too long. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right--the pipeline spins up a new virtual machine for each build. Your only other option is likely to include those dependencies in the build input.